# jquery-ui interfering with css on page load in IE9

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9, sticky-footer

I am trying to apply this sticky footer pattern to my template:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

But in **Internet Explorer 9**, I am seeing a scroll bar, and if I scroll down lots of white space appearing below the footer:

[image: White space]

It gets even weirder, as I stripped more and more out of my template until I was left with just basic layout, bootstrap, footer css, jquery and jquery-ui.

Jquery and jquery-ui libraries are merely included in the head, no other java script loads that could call them.

The problem still manifests, until I remove jquery-ui from the head. Then the page renders ok.

Here are some live examples:

[With jquery-ui](http://tcusers.com/examples/34456284736/with-jquery-ui.htm)

[Without jquery-ui](http://tcusers.com/examples/34456284736/without-jquery-ui.htm)

Also, the white space disappears if I resize the window. Clutching at straws I've even tried triggering $(window).resize() on page load, but no such luck.

Does anyone have any idea why oh why internet explorer 9 is adding this mysterious white space and how to make it stop? I thought IE9 was supposed to be the most compliant of the IE species...

Thanks for any help, I've been pulling my hair out all day over this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resorted to debugging jquery-ui, found some obscure code that runs on document ready that appends a div to the end of a page to fix a 3 year old IE6 issue!

jQuery UI 1.8.17 Line 225:

```
var body = document.body,
        div = body.appendChild( div = document.createElement( "div" ) );

$.extend( div.style, {
        minHeight: "100px",
        height: "auto",
        padding: 0,
        borderWidth: 0
});

$.support.minHeight = div.offsetHeight === 100;
$.support.selectstart = "onselectstart" in div;

// set display to none to avoid a layout bug in IE
// http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4014
body.removeChild( div ).style.display = "none";
```

Removing this fixes my problem, I think IE9 compatibility is more important than IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any css class names shared with jQuery UI? They all start with `ui-`, e.g. `ui-icon`, `ui-widget-content`, etc. Take a look at [CSS Framework docs](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API) for more information.

Comment: Nope, see the source of the live examples, not using any ui- prefixed classes.